# What kernel level functions are called when we perform write in ext3 file system?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext3

I have ext3 file system mounted and I am creating a file on it to understand how block groups are allocated.

I want to know what functions are being called when I create/write a file. I know `vfs_write` is called and thereafter I am confused what all functions are called. (`do_sync_write` is mentioned but I am not sure if it's write).

Specifically, I don't want my files to exceed 2 block groups (trying to limit the size. 1 GB contains ~32768 blocks which are of 4K size each). Also, I am new to system programming so any help or direction will be great.

Comment: Have you tried the strace command?

Comment: No, I haven't tried strace yet. I am new to systems programming. Do you recommend trying strace? I can try that.

Comment: @donjuedo - strace - ok I tried and it will not help. It's good if you need to know how ls is performing, but here I am looking for something which can help me know what functions or methods in kernel are called from vfs_write when write to a file is done.

Comment: Why do you ask? From a user-land perspective, a `write`  is to some opened file descriptor related to a file in a filesystem thru the VFS, and it does not matter if the file sits in some Ext3 filesystem or some VFAT one...